# IdentityServer4, Angular and .NET CORE Api

Tags: angular, identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm using IdentityServer4 with ASP.NET Identity and Angular for the client. All is good and working as I expect when I have a user logged in. The question is regarding securing access to the Api to just my Angular app for anonymous users. For example I don't want just anyone accessing the endpoint to create users. Does the Angular app need to get a token to using the client credentials? This token would then be used for anonymous users.

New to OAUTH and trying to get my understanding straight.

Comment: Client credentials is not a valid flow as the client can't keep a secret. In fact this approach is quite dangerous as anyone can impersonate the client using these credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not need to get a token to access endpoints such as create user, since it is normally an `[AllowAnonymous]` action. If you really do wish to constrain access to this endpoint, then it can be achieved using different kind of measures, such as [CORS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2) for example.

Comment: While you can argue about the first line, the answer is indeed that this has to be achieved in a different way.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg agreed, that’s why i tried to stay neutral with the first line saying “normally”

Comment: Thanks to both, very helpful. I'm also using CORS, but wasn't sure I was leaving something on the table by not exploring a client token as an option.